# Electric field at the center of a square

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry

Let be a square composed by a wire uniformely charged, the electric field at its center should be zero because the contribution of every infinitesimal element of the wire is compensated by its symmetric regarding to the center. 
But it doesn't seem to be so because the field at the center is computable and non-zero.
Could someone please explain in what way my considering the situation is wrong?

Comment: please be more clear

Comment: If you say that the field is computable and non-zero, what is your answer for what the field is?

Comment: I should clear up the situation: we were given this case in an exercise in class. The correction says you have to integrate the field on one side and multiply the result by four (for each side), but that's all it says. So I drew a sketch to figure out the situation, and on my sketch all of the vectorial dE compensate each other, so that the vectorial sum seems to be 0. I don't understand the correction.

Comment: The field _is_ zero at the center.

Comment: So... would it mean that the correction's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the problem asks for the field and not the potential? The potential at the center of the square is the sum of four identical terms and is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your argumentation makes sense. Because the location of the charges displays a point symmetry w.r.t. to the center of the square, both the potential and the electric field display a point symmetry w.r.t. to the center of the square. A vector field displaying a point symmetry at a given point must be zero at that point, hence the electric field is zero at the center of the square.

Addendum: the above argumentation applies to a vector field but not to a scalar field, and in particular the potential can be non zero.